# Fireworks running slowly, objects disappearing from animation

Tags: speed, adobe-cs5, adobe-fireworks

I created a simple animation in Fireworks, but it apparently has disappeared. A small sphere which appears in the first frame (or state) is visible. Although it is supposed to start moving, it however just sits still and disappears when the animation is run.

Yet the sphere itself is a symbol. When I click on it, the rest of the animation is visible. I can press *play* and the whole animation is visible.

But Fireworks now runs sooooo slowly. It takes half a minute to go from one frame to the next!

What is going on? How can I hope to edit and add to my animation if Fireworks is running this slow? And no - it ain't hardware: I have 4 Gigs of RAM!

Comment: Can you upload it and we can try ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds, to me, like you made the animation within the symbol itself. (I just tested it and it behaved just as you said.) If this had of been Flash, you would have been fine. But it's not, so we got issues!

**IF** this is what you did, you should be able to right-click on the ball in the first frame and under the Symbol menu, hit Break Apart.

As for running slow... That tends to happen within fireworks with large animations. Once you export the final product, that should run just fine. Well, as fine as a large animation can.

Comment: I think what I did might prove entirely incurable. I did a lot of tweening, and make a lot of symbols. I did whatever it took to not have the situation where objects either (a) insisted on being present in every single state whenever they were inserted or (b) tweening that failed to put the animation in different states and instead insisted on creating an appalling blur in a single state!

Comment: The animation will run fine; my computer is just about powerful enough to handle it! However, editing has now become an impossibility as it takes between a half minute to a minute to perform any action in fireworks. I think I will concede defeat and just have to live with the half baked animation as there isn't time to start over from scratch!